# How can I set different bottom margin for first and following pages?

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a mpdf object in which I write some HTML code

```
$mpdf->AddPage('P', '', '', '', '', 20, 20, 25, 30, 15, 5);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

I don't know how many pages will result. `$html` could contain a lot of text or just a couple of lines;

But the bottom margin should be set to a different value starting from the second page because I have a big footer only in the first page but not in the following.

I already tried playing around with `setAutoBottomMargin` but with no success

Is there a way to obtain this using mPfd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using @page as described [**here**](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html)

Since @page support pseudo selectors ([**here**](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html#pseudo-selectors)) I was able to do

```
@page :first{
    margin-bottom: 30mm;
    margin-top: 60mm; 
}

@page {
    margin-bottom: 25mm;
    margin-top: 25mm; 
}
```

this set different margins for the first and the following pages